# Over current context presentation with gestures

Tags: swift, viewcontroller

I am trying to implement the functionality of Youtube's video player. ATM I have a `FloatingViewController` (the video player) which gets presented modally (overCurrentContext) on a `MainViewController` which has it's `definesPresentationContext` set to true.

Everything works fine except the touch recognition (no scrolling) on the `MainViewController` when I pull down the player into *minimized* mode. I am pretty sure that this is happening because the `FloatingViewController`'s view (with a clear background) is over every view in the `MainVC` as it got presented over it.

Mostly looking for any solutions or workarounds...

[image: preview]

Yellow thingy is the FloatingVC. The rest is MainVC...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was (as I've mentioned) another view (a `UITransitionView`) underlying the `FloatingVC`. This view is there because of the `present(...)` method call. Fixed it by using `addChildVC` instead and also animating the addition of the VC's view...

Answer (score 0):

Try to check overlapping one view by the other one using debug view hierarchy in xcode.

[image: debug view hierarchy in xcode]